# ImportError: No module named reflect

Tags: python, python-requests

My "import reflects" (Python) does not works.

I am using this code:

```
import reflect
p = inflect.engine()
```

I have received this message

> ImportError: No module named reflect

What I should do?  Step by step please.  I have already downloaded `inflect-0.2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl` but I do not know how to open it.

Comment: Did you install `reflect`?  It will be hard to import if you haven't installed it.  The easiest way to install it is `pip install reflect`.

Comment: you are importing a module called *reflect*, and then trying to access a module called *inflect*. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Install your downloaded .whl file using the following command:

```
[root@server] python -m pip install /<path>/inflect-0.2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Once that's installed you should be able to access the module by running the following

```
[root@server] python
>> import inflect
>>
>> p = inflect.engine()
```